# pip list and pip install are referring to different site-packages

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I am having a weird issue with PIP:

The following is where my pip is located:

`which pip` returns...
`/usr/local/bin/pip`, which is a link to...
`/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin/pip`

If I do a `pip install flask` and then a`pip list`, I see that flask doesn't appear

```
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (5.4.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

However, I see that flask appears in `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

```
ls /lib/python2.7/site-packages/ | grep flask
flask
```

I found some other site-packages areas, where nothing is installed and am wondering if that's where `pip list` is trying to access:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

TL;DR: pip list is referencing one site-packages and pip install is referencing another. Yes, I am using the same pip (/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin//pip), which was installed by `brew install python`

EDIT:

sys.path produces...

```
 ['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: What happens when you use the *full path* of the command? `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin/pip list` and `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin/pip install flask`?

Comment: When running both with the full path, I don't see flask installed with the list option, despite the install option showing that flask was installed.

Comment: Are there any `Flask-*-py2.7.egg-info` directories in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` or `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?

Comment: What does `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'` produce? Have you looked at the `site-packages` directories listed by that result?

Comment: I think that the Flask installed in `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` is a red herring and has nothing to do with your current problems.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/p‌​ython2.7/site-packages` are the same. The second is a symlink to the first.

Comment: actually, that's the first time I ever installed flask, and it shows the correct timestamp. pip is definitely installing flask to `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: I have no such directory on my Mac system. `/lib` doesn't even exist.

Comment: thanks. no idea where `/lib` came from. seems like brew is to blame. I installed everything with brew, repeatedly. Unloaded my entire bash_profile as well before doing so. I'll try installing python from python.org.

Comment: I use [buildout.python](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python) to build my Pythons on Mac..

Comment: How did `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` end up on your `sys.path`? Is it possible that you have _three_ Pythons, not just two (as in Apple's pre-installed Python, and Homebrew Python, and also python.org Python), and one of the two extra ones has overwritten stuff used by the other?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on. I tried abandoning the brew route, and downloading python and distribute from their websites. After `brew uninstall` and resetting my environment var's, I install python, then try to install distribute with `python distribute.py` and it tries to install it to `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` again!